# ActionView::Template::Error (db_name must be a string or symbol):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, unicorn

Ok so i have a new rails app that i have on ubuntu 11.10 on ec2 and it has mongoid as the db and i keep getting this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (db_name must be a string or symbol):
```

Here is my config/mongoid.yml

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: mm_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: mm_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019
```

and my database.yml is blank because i didnt know what if anything needs to go there. Here is my gemfile for mongoid

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'mongoid'
```

First i want to know if anyone know what i need to do with database.yml and then how do i solve this issue....mongo is up and running but this error is confusing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run with blank config/database.yml or remove it, you must remove all references to Active Record.  The following worked for me, check it for config/application.rb and what I had to do to get a fresh Rails project to pass an initial test with your supplied Gemfile and config/mongoid.yml.  Note that you also should comment out "fixtures :all" in test/test_helper.rb.  I recommend that you recreate your equivalent of the following as a clean base from which to start.  Hope that this helps.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
$ rails _3.2.3_ new free-11137-db_name
$ cd free-11137-db_name

Gemfile as per user

$ bundle install
$ gem install unicorn
$ bundle install
Using mongo (1.6.2)
Using mongoid (2.4.8)

$ rails g mongoid:config

config/mongoid.yml as per user
config/database.yml blank as per user
config/application.rb
    #require 'rails/all'
    require "action_controller/railtie"
    require "action_mailer/railtie"
    require "active_resource/railtie"
    require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
    # require "sprockets/railtie" # Uncomment this line for Rails 3.1+

remove all references to Active Record as follows
    config/application.rb
        #config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    config/environments/development.rb
        #config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
        #config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

    config/environments/test.rb
      #config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

    test/test_helper.rb
        #fixtures :all

$ rails g model person
$ cat app/models/person.rb
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
end
$ rm test/fixtures/people.yml
$ bundle exec rake test # succeeds
$ rm config/database.yml
$ bundle exec rake test # succeeds
```